# Can't resolve symbol "Plus" in android google plus integration project

Tags: android, google-plus

Try to integrate google plus in my app, but can't find 'com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus' class. I update the google play service according to the latest release .

MainActivity.java:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                    this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addScope(Scopes.PLUS_ME)
            .build();
```

build.gradle(Project level):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common     to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
 }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
 }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(app level):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.apt.googleintegration"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: add the following in your app's gradle file  `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'`

Comment: Thanks, it is  working

Comment: If the solution worked then @Subham please accept the answer posted below so that it would helpful for future visitors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work if you add the following in your gradle file

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'`